# Are triangulations of polygons 3-colourable?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs, triangulation

Let us take a polygon and divide it into triangles in an arbitrary manner. When playing with such triangulations, I was not able to generate any which were not 3-colourable.

Is it true in general that they are 3-colourable?  If not, can someone give a counterexample?

Here are two examples to illustrate clearly what I mean by "triangulation" and "colouring".

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: At least in the examples you've given, you can always remove a triangle that has one external edge and you're left with a smaller region, which can be 3-colored by induction. Since the removed triangle has at most two neighbors, it can be given a color without conflicts.

Comment: @lhf If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The problem with my argument is that removing that triangle or just its external edge may leave us with something that is not a triangulation of a simple polygon when the other vertex of the triangle is a vertex of the polygon. The argument may be salvaged by considering two separate regions but I don't know the details.

Comment: @lhf You mean that e.g. removing [the pink triangle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vYCYu.png) will disconnect the graph?

Comment: Yes, exactly... Perhaps it is easier to prove something slightly stronger: for regions with multiple connected components where you allow two components to have 1 vertex in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [Brooks's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem), which says:

> For any connected undirected graph $G$ with maximum degree $\Delta$, the chromatic number of $G$ is at most $\Delta$ unless $G$ is a complete graph or an odd cycle, in which case the chromatic number is $\Delta+1$.

A triangle can have at most 3 neighbours, so the maximum degree is 3.

Let us look at the exceptions mentioned by the theorem:

(Odd) cycles have max-degree 2, so they are still 3-colourable.

Complete graphs with more than 4 vertices are not planar, thus not realizable as a triangulation.  The complete graph with 4 vertices cannot be realized as a triangulation either because if two neighbours of a triangle are adjacent, they cannot be also adjacent to the third neighbour.  Complete graphs with less than 4 vertices are 3-colourable.

Thus it is true that any triangulation of a polygon is 3-colourable.